# Mootools conflict in Kunena

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools

I'm having a small issue with my Joomla 3.0 site working with Kunena.

There is no problem with Joomla and Kunena with the default joomla template. However with new template called *meet_gavern* the BBCode editor in Kunena doesn't load,the profile edit page doesn't work and the upload attachment to any post is buggy.

I've searched a lot for the problem and it seems to be a conflict with Jquery from the template and Kunena's loding of Mootools.

When I go to the forum page on the website tHe console logs an error

```
ReferenceError: Hash is not defined
    var KCookie = new Hash.Cookie('kunena_toggler', {path: '/', duration: 0});
```

The file in reference to the error above is /media/kunena/js/default.js (line 801)

Is there any way to fix this? I cannot change the template right now as a lot of work has gone into customizing it.

Template layout file has this. Not sure if it will help

```
// Rules to remove predefined jQuery and Bootstrap and MooTools More
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/jui\/js\/jquery.min.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/jui\/js\/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/jui\/js\/bootstrap.min.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/system\/js\/mootools-more.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
```

Comment: I am not allowed to post a link. But this is the template I'm using http://joomla30.gavick.com/
I cant seem to locate the file where I can change the order Mootools and Jquery are loaded.

Comment: @Kunema is built with Mootools as I can see. `Hash` is in Mootools More. Can you post the js files you are loading? is Mootools-More there?

Comment: no mootools-more is not loaded. However I do see my template layout file having the code i just appended to my main post

Comment: Solved! . I uncommented that last line that strips out mootools-more.js. The problem is gone. THanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction Sergio! :)

Comment: Please add a definite answer so I can select yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kunema is built with Mootools and `Hash` is part of Mootools More.

If I comment out the line

```
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/system\/js\/mootools-more.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
```

in the template's layout file located in the template directory at

```
/layout/default.php
```

then the problem is solved.

Kunena needs `mootools-more.js` to run as well. The template was stripping out the file and preventing it from being loaded.

Comment: I think the answer you posted is clear. Keep it. Happy I could help!